# C# Split a string in four equal substrings but only at newline

Tags: c#, regex, string, memory, split

I received an out of memory exception with the following code which splits a large string (the str variable) into lines and enqueues them:

```
 foreach (
            var value in
                str.Split(
                    new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) },
                       StringSplitOptions.None))
                {
                    lines.Enqueue(value);
                }
```

My solution (which I'm not sure is a good one) is to first split the large string (the str variable) into 4 chunks and then split each chunk separately and enqueue the resulting lines in the lines queue. The problem I'm having is figuring out how to split on a newline so my eventual lines queue contains only complete lines.

I wrote the following code to split the large string (the str variable) into 4 substrings but how can I change it to split on a newline only?

```
      int chunkNum = 4;
      int chunkLength = str.Length/chunkNum;
      int stringLength = str.Length;
      var j = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkLength)
           {
              if (j == (chunkNum - 1))
              {
                  chunkLength = stringLength - i;
              }

              chunkQueue.Enqueue(str.Substring(i, chunkLength + i));
              j++;
            }
```

Comment: as an aside comment, writing `int stringLength = str.Length; int chunkLength = stringLength/chunkNum;` isn't better?

Comment: You can search from each chunk end offset the position of the next newline character with `indexOf("\n", endOffset)`, then you redefine each chunk start and end offsets. (you must do that before really spliting, it is only arithmetic)

Comment: Definitely on your first comment. On the second comment I had that thought and then thought I would count the "\n" and divide and split at the nth occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `StreamReader` which provides `ReadLine` method.

```
string text = "Split\nby\nnewline", line = "";
using( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( new MemoryStream( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( text ) ) ) ) {
    while( ( line = sr.ReadLine() ) != null )
        Console.WriteLine( line );
}
```

Does that suite your needs? Just enqueue the string instead of printing it.

Answer (score 0):

If the input string is that huge, you probably got it from a Stream (file?) anyway.
Maybe you could just read that stream character by character, append to a Stringbuilder, and Enqueue when the character is a newline?

Ah, just missed pikausp's answer, which makes a lot more sense...

Comment: I probably should have but I'm a beginner. It came from an AJAX call in chunks and I used StringBuilder.